# Preserve query params duiring the redirect with Traefik

Tags: regex, http, traefik

Subj, I'm trying to receive query params after redirecting from Traefik, to accomplish my flow. I expected it out-of-the-box (if don't specify details request details would be preserved) - but it seems like Traefik can't do it, or I missed something.

So, f.e., the initial request is

```
https://company.com/oauth/callback?code=blabla
```

and redirected request is the following (without `code` param)

```
https://company.com/blabla/#/oauth/callback
```

There are the following configs:

apps-ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: company-platform-apps
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - http
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: 'Host(${SOME_HOST}) && PathPrefix(`/oauth/callback`)'
      middlewares:
        - name: auth-redirect
      services:
        - kind: TraefikService
          name: noop@internal
```

apps-middleware.yaml

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: company-platform-apps-stripprefix
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
    - /prefix

---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: auth-redirect
spec:
  redirectRegex:
    permanent: true
    regex: '(http[s]?:\/\/[^\/\s]+)(.*)$'
    replacement: '$${1}/blabla/#/oauth/callback'
```

Please don't hesitate to ping if you have any suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, it's more in regex dimension, so the following change brings the expected behaviour:

```
spec:
  redirectRegex:
    permanent: true
    regex: '^(http[s]?:\/\/[^\/]+)?(\/[^?]+)?(\?[^#]+)?$'
    replacement: '$${1}/blabla/#/oauth/callback$${3}'
```

This `regex` operates with 3 groups - host, path and query params, so we just add 3rd group with params to `replacement` - and that's it!