Traefik RedirectRegex
I am using Traefik RedirectRegex. I need to redirect from

https://oldwebsite.com  to https://new-website.domain.com/internal
https://oldwebsite.com/12345 to https://new-website.domain.com/internal/12345
https://oldwebsite.com/12345/orders to https://new-website.domain.com/internal/12345/orders
https://oldwebsite.com/12345/orders?id=12 to https://new-website.domain.com/internal/12345/orders?id=12

My setup now :
- "traefik.http.routers.redirect-router.entrypoints=https"
- "traefik.http.routers.redirect-router.rule=Host(`oldwebsite.com`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.redirect-router.middlewares=redirect-regex"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-regex.redirectregex.regex=(.)*"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-regex.redirectregex.replacement=https://new-website.domain.com/internal$${2}"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-regex.redirectregex.permanent=true"

Now it redirects only from https://oldwebsite.com to https://new-website.domain.com/internal without path/query parameters. Based on the documentation $${2} and $${3} are responsible for it?

I think your regex is at fault here. (.)* - that's a capture group that will capture one arbitrary character, and you are allowing for multiple of these capture groups. So $${1} would gives you access to the first character, $${2} to the second, and so on - makes little sense. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/77316754/1427878 for an example on how to do the matching and capturing of a URL and its parts correctly.

@C3roe thanks! I have changed to regex=https://oldwebsite.com(.*) and replacement=https://new-website.domain.com/internal$${1}  but it`s still looks wrong....

The answer in that other discussion suggests that this matches against the full URL, so you would be capturing https://oldwebsite.com/12345/orders with that, and then append that to the end of https://new-website.domain.com/internal, which would make rather little sense. Suggest you go with the expression suggested there, that should allow you to capture all the parts you need, https://regex101.com/r/96CamT/1

@C3roe it throws : yaml error: found unknown escape character. Btw why official documentation says that $${1} is enough? https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/redirectregex/

Because their pattern there only has one capture group.

I can't tell which syntax format you are actually using, is this supposed to be YAML now? Or does what you have shown above somehow convert/compile to YAML? (They got an extra tab labeled "File (YAML)" there, and the syntax in there is differently; notably, the dollar signs are not doubled in that one.)

Thank you, I'll look into it. It doesn't work for me now even with one capture group (case 2). Maybe there is some other problem

# Traefik dynamic config
# Redirect with domain replacement
# Note: all dollar signs need to be doubled for escaping.
labels:
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.regex=^https://oldwebsite.com/(.*)"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.replacement=https://new-website.domain.com/internal/$${1}"

